How to make my webapp execute a python function on certain days at certain times with Celery?
I'm making a webapp stored on google cloud. For my backend I use Flask, Python, Celery and RabbitMQ. For my frontend I use React, JavaScript and HTML/CSS. I code on VS Code.
I tried making a schedule.json to determine which day my function should be called, but for testing I only put "print hello" every X minute, because I thought that if I understand the way it works it would be easy to scale it to my calendar:
{
    "print-hello-14-10": {
        "task": "app.tasks.print_hello",
        "schedule": {
            "hour": 14,
            "minute": 10
        }
    },
    "print-hello-14-11": {
        "task": "app.tasks.print_hello",
        "schedule": {
            "hour": 14,
            "minute": 11
        }
    }
}

I made four .py files.
My init.py file:
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.update(
        CELERY_BROKER_URL='amqps://<username>:<password>@<hostname>/<vhost>',
        CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='rpc://',
    )
    from .tasks import init_celery
    init_celery(app)
    return app

My make_celery.py file:
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
        backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    return celery

My run.py file:
from app import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

My tasks.py file:
import os
import json
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

celery = Celery(__name__)

def init_celery(app=None):
    app.config.update(
        CELERY_BROKER_URL='amqp://<username>:<password>@<hostname>/<vhost>',
        CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='rpc://',
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    if app:
        celery.conf.update(app.config)
    update_schedule_from_json()

@celery.task
def print_hello():
    print('Hello')

def update_schedule_from_json():
    schedule_file = 'schedule.json'
    if os.path.exists(schedule_file):
        with open(schedule_file, 'r') as f:
            schedule_data = json.load(f)
        celery.conf.beat_schedule = {}
        for key, value in schedule_data.items():
            celery.conf.beat_schedule[key] = {
                'task': value['task'],
                'schedule': crontab(hour=value['schedule']['hour'], minute=value['schedule']['minute']),
            }

# Call this function to update the schedule whenever necessary
update_schedule_from_json()

I try to launch it by running my Flask app like this python run.py, then running my celery worker in a terminal with celery -A app.tasks worker --loglevel=info and running my celerey beat scheduler in a separate terminal with celery -A app.tasks beat --loglevel=info.
It is not working, though I managed to have my print hello work when I used a fixed interval (without all the scheduling stuff). So I think that my scheduler is the problem but I don't know what to modify. I call for your help.

You want to pass day_of_week into the crontab call. You can find examples in the celery docs here: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules
